# How to automate access token retrieval using Authorization code flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0

We are working on web application which interacts with Microsoft Graph/OneDrive using REST APIs. 
We are using Authorization code flow to obtain access token.

This flow presents Microsoft login page & consent page which we are looking to automate. As this UI is tend to change we could not leverage Selenium or similar framework.

Could you please help/suggest framework/technology to automate such flow?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Authorization code flow. Use client credentials grant flow. 
More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).

Comment: We have decided to use Password grant oauth flow as automation server runs on-premise and in secured environment.

Comment: Password grant is not considered secure and it is removed from Oauth 2.1 standard. If you have secure envirement why do you use Oauth?